How to Design an Efficient H Bridge using MOSFET for DC Motor (12 V)?
I would like to ask what is the most efficient H-Bridge design using MOSFETs (IRF9540N and IRF9540N). I found many references in this forum like using and I am still confused to decide. My goal is to design an H Bride to drive a DC Motor (12 Volts) and minimize the risk of exploding the MOSFET. DC Motor to drive the Line Follower Robot. I need to make Driver manually not using Module.

What have you tried so far? Have you seen this: Why can't I get rid of shoot-through in my half-bridge circuit?

To be honest, i still doing research about this circuit.

There are off-the-shelf solutions made by TI. At least one is called DRVnnnn. I can't remember what the nnnn bit is but  believe it begins with an * hence DRV8nnn.

Yeah, i just have checked it on google and i found it. But my aim is to created Driver Motor manually and does not use any IC components. @Andyaka

This is a reference I found H-Bridge. But I don't know if it is efficient or not?

That look OK for moderate switching speeds but, if you are expecting to use PWM at anything over a few hundred Hz it'll burn. Or, use PWM as they suggest.

Ah okay, If I use a DC Motor (3-6V), what components should I replace? Or i just use the same circuit?
